# Use angular to call multiple actions from Node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

Please help, I'm unflushed in programming   . I created a route `router.get('/statistics', routesCtrl.statistics)` for a page where I want to display some statistics in some charts, using Angular.

I realized that I need to send some query results like, how many registrations are in db, how many of them have "this property", how many of them have “those properties” and so on, being something new for me. Until now in responses of the routes I sent only one statistic from the above list.

How should I send this info to Angular, should I create a literal object containing those statistics, packing them in the response and send it to the Angular? Or to send the entire json from db and parse it in Angular, but it seems to be a wrong idea also because I can't use then mongoose queries from Angular if it's true :) .

I don’t have any other idea and there probably are more professional ways. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple, whenever you need data from server side, which is node.js in your case or anything it may be like PHP, asp.nrt etc you have to send http requests to server using angular $http (GET/POST) and along with required parameters as a json object or query string. At server end write some rest service type stuff to handle this and make use of send parmeters at server to query mongo and than pass collected data as a json object back to angular end. At angular you can parse this JSON, and angular have also scope to use JSON/Array directly in view using  attribute ng-repeat and so on depends on your exact requirement.

Request in angular.js

```
var sendConfig = {
        method : "POST",
        url: "YOUR_URL",
        data: {action : 'Test_Service'},
        headers : {}
      };


      $http(sendConfig).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);

      }).error(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
});
```

Response In node.js

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){

    var webservice_actions_instance = new webservice_actions(req, res);
    var service_response = {data : 'RESPONSE_HERE_AFTER_CERTAIN_ALGOS'};

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html',"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*","Access-Control-Allow-Headers":" X-Requested-With"});
    res.write('Response Data '+ service_response);
    res.end();  



}).listen( 8080 );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How should I include all my info in the response that should be sent to Angular? Should I use Async.js?

Comment: @Webdesigner i have added a most basic structure of restservice usage.. please let me know if need any help..

Comment: Thank you for the example, I really apreaciate your effort. My issue is that I need to display on the client some data. For example displaying per month the OS used by users to apply a form. So, this means I should interrogate the db to obtain something like: {January: {Android: 30, iOS: 10, winPhone: 5}, February: {Android: 4, iOS: 40}, etc}. The problem it was how to create multiple queries and unify the results in one response. I found out that I can use async.parallel and now I try to figure out how can I create this query with mongoose, but probably I'll succeed :)